# Unplug C Drive to Run Linux without drive damage

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot

My PC is currently running windows 8. I would like to run my linux distro from a USB stick. I would like to eliminate all unnecessary heat, so I would like to unplug my C drive while running the linux distro.

My question is -

Can I unplug the sata and power cable to my C drive, boot from my USB, then when I am done, remove the USB, plug the C drive back in and boot back into windows without any damage to the C drive.

I understand I can change the boot order and boot directly from the USB stick with the C drive plugged in, although I'm not looking to do that.

Comment: plugging a drive out (after dismounting it) is one thing.  Plugging it in when the computer is on.. I suppose you could be a bit of a pioneer, but then you're being a bit of a guinea pig.

Comment: if you did it (plugging it in) from the BIOS setup screen, then at least you know the hard drive isn't being written to when you plug it in, but then the BIOS won't have the right data until a restart, so it's a bit odd. And there's no advantage to that. You may as well turn it off.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you turn off your computer first, then also turn off your power supply (the switch on the back if your computer has one) then you should be fine. It's a good idea to leave your computer plugged in and just turn off the power because then it remains grounded. If there is no switch at the back, unplug it completely. Make sure to keep in contact with the case to equalize any electric potential difference between you and the computer. Also don't directly touch any connectors or you could discharge static electricity to them.

If its not absolutely necessary, I wouldn't recommend removing your hard drive, they usually don't generate that much heat.

Comment: -1 he obviously knows that a drive can be unplugged when the computer is off.

Comment: @barlop I don't understand why you down voted my answer. If he did know he could unplug the drive when the computer is off, why would he be posting this question? I mentioned in my answer to turn of the computer to be sure he did not attempt this while his computer is still on.

Comment: If he was asking if a drive can b unplugged when a comp is off, then the q has no value, because this site is a database of questions and answers and it has no use to anybody else 'cos nobody else would search for the answer to such a bad question of  if a hard drive can be unplugged when a computer is off.U interpreted his question that way as soon as your answer started.He might be asking, (or you could interpret his question), as plugging it in/out when the computer is on.If you began with that, then as an additional point,mentioned about  'off' (in case he didn't know) then it'd be better